# How to resolve `! Undefined control sequence. \GenericError` with forest and comma in math mode

Tags: tikz-pgf, forest

I want to write the following code:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
[ \(R(x, f)\)
        [x]
        [f]
]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

Which gives the following error

```
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg))
! Undefined control sequence.
\GenericError  ...                                
                                                    #4  \errhelp \@err@     ...
l.11 \end{forest}
                 
?
```

Interestingly, if I remove the `,` the code works.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
[ \(R(x f)\)
        [x]
        [y]
]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Put it in braces: `{\(R(x, f)\)}`.

Comment: @Marijn Yes!, Thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

Solutions from @Marjin -  Use braces: `{\(R(x, f)\)}`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
[ {\(R(x, f)\)}
        [x]
        [y]
]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```